# How to monitor LOG after a phrase, and trigger a USB reset?

Tags: linux

I need help to monitor my log and find a especific phrase, and after that, reset my usb device!

I tried Unbind and Bind But I don't thing it worked...After my tests I found out the usb device has no symlink and the device change ports.

I found this for the monitoring part:

> line=$(  grep -m 1 YourKeyWord <( exec tail -f /directory/of/log.out ); kill $! 2> /dev/null)

```
if [ "$line"!="" ]
then
echo "Found $line"
service something start
line=""
echo "Now we can look for ABC"
fi
```

My question about this: The Tail will keep going?

And for the USB reset I found those 2 codes:

```
#!/bin/bash
#type lsusb to find "vendor" and "product" ID in terminal
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

#edit the below two lines of vendor and product values using lsusb result
dev=$(lsusb -t | grep usbdevicename | grep 'If 1' | cut -d' ' -f13|cut -d"," -f1)
#VENDOR=05a3
#PRODUCT=9230
VENDOR=$(lsusb -s $dev | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d: -f1)
PRODUCT=$(lsusb -s $dev | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d: -f2)

for DIR in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 1 -type l); do
  if [[ -f $DIR/idVendor && -f $DIR/idProduct &&
        $(cat $DIR/idVendor) == $VENDOR && $(cat $DIR/idProduct) == $PRODUCT ]]; then
    echo 0 > $DIR/authorized
    sleep 0.5
    echo 1 > $DIR/authorized
  fi
done



#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

VENDOR="045e"
PRODUCT="0719"

for DIR in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/ -maxdepth 1 -type l); do
  if [[ -f $DIR/idVendor && -f $DIR/idProduct &&
        $(cat $DIR/idVendor) == $VENDOR && $(cat $DIR/idProduct) == $PRODUCT ]]; then
    echo 0 > $DIR/authorized
    sleep 0.5
    echo 1 > $DIR/authorized
  fi
done
```

I need help to know whats the best choice, and if anyone know the best solution for this...For the usb reset I discovered SEC, but I'm trying to do this without installing anything...Thanks in advance!

Comment: take the time to disect this code and execute it step by step to understand what the differences are (and what are the trade-offs).  To see if the `tail -f` continues running, learn to use `ps -ef | grep '[t]ail'` from a separate window/terminal session. Good luck.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.

I tried the monitoring part without sucess...I got a command substitution : line 2: error...sintaxe error next to (...Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I can try to help you as I have time available. Update you Q with the exact text of the error message please. You can also debug better by adding `set -x` after the first line of your script. This will show you each command as it is executed with all environment variables expanded to their current values. Good luck.

Comment: Also if you are running these commands from the command line (as I suggest) and are having trouble with `$(...)` then please also include the output of `echo "SHELL=$SHELL"`. Good luck.